# just for studies, how could I finish my imcros code in javascript?

Tags: javascript, replace, eval, extract, imacros

something wrong in my code for imacros?

```
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=STRONG ATTR=TXT:monkey EXTRACT=TXT
SET !VAR1 EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.replace(/ke\w+?/g, '');")
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ACTION:index.php?c=1 ATTR=NAME:captcha_answer CONTENT={{!VAR1}}
```

when I convert to javascript using the cade creator I get the following error

SyntaxError: missing ; before statement, line 5 (Error code: -991)

My code is below

```
var n = '\n';
var code = '';
code += 'CODE: \n SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO \n';
code += 'TAG POS=1 TYPE=STRONG ATTR=TXT:monkey EXTRACT=TXT' + n;
code += 'SET !VAR1 EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.replace(/ke\w+?/g, '');")' + n;
code += 'TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ACTION:* ATTR=NAME:* CONTENT={{!VAR1}}' + n;
code += 'WAIT SECONDS=1' + n;
iimPlay(code, 60);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the line

```
code += 'SET !VAR1 EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.replace(/ke\w+?/g, '');")' + n;
```

with

```
code += 'SET !VAR1 EVAL("\'{{!EXTRACT}}\'.replace(/ke\\w+?/g, \'\');")' + n;
```